# Navmeshagent not working with animator enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to unity and followed a tutorial to put a walking animation on my npc character when it starts to move. What it does instead is float above its starting location and not move. No animations play either. When I uncheck the animator component, the NPC moves like its supposed to. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class GrandpaNav : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform movePositionTransform;
    [SerializeField] Animator Animator;
    private const string IsWalking = "IsWalking";
    private const string IsRunning = "IsRunning";
    private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        navMeshAgent.destination = movePositionTransform.position;
        Animator.SetBool(IsWalking, navMeshAgent.velocity.magnitude > 0.01f);
    }
}
```

And I’ve attached a screenshot from the animator with one of the transitions selected. They are all identical. Running is not enabled yet, I’m just trying to get walking functional first.

[image: Unity Screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked that the animation clip has loop time and loop pose enabled? Also, what does the preview of the animation look like? Is it also in the air?

Comment: If the animations are all fine, a good way to see what is happening, is to set the character moving, pause, and view the colliders/nav agent boxes in the scene view. Sounds like you may need to change the NavMeshAgent base offset.